# Ubuntu 20.04.4 GNOME with scale 200% on 4K monitor - application windows are maximized beyond screen on re-login

Tags: nvidia, gnome, display-resolution

When I lock my screen then come back after some time to login, whatever window I was using before will be maximized beyond my screen where I can no longer see the bar at the top of the window for me to minimize / maximize / close. For example in Firefox, it will just show me a portion of the web page and I cannot see my tabs or anything at the top of the window to reset the window to fit within my screen. To fix this I need to close the application or click at the top bar where my clock is and quickly drag down. This happens around half of the time.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using 3.36.8 with X11 windowing system with a NVIDIA graphics card with proprietary NVIDIA drivers installed. This happens when my resolution is 3840 x 2160 and have the scale set to 200%. I'm trying out 1920 x 1080 resolution with 100% scale and haven't noticed the issue yet.

Comment: to get out of the situation you can open a terminal and use xrandr to set you resolution. I had the same problem on log-ins and i just put a script on a launcher on one of my panels that I would click on every log in(because I was too lazy to fix the actual problem). I thought I had another similar situation where creating an xorg.conf and hard-setting the modeline to the desired resolution worked to fix that problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but I suffer similar problems.
In one of my workstations I have a 4K monitor and another just FullHD, with Ubuntu 20.04.4 I suffer this issues:

- after starting Firefox with a previous session, many times, some of the instances believe that they are maximized but they are using only 1/4 of the screen, with no maximize button clickable.
- After a File selection window is displayed if I try to move it it converts the main window to a mini window where I don't have buttons and I can't maximize it.
- When I drag and drop one window to another monitor some times it does the same
- Similar behavior to yours, with window maximized and no buttons to restore the size.

In all the cases I use an old trick I learned many years ago.
Being the focus in the window I want to fix I press ALT + Space.
This brings a text menu were you can select Minimize, Maximize, Move, Move Title bar on screen, Resize, etc...
If you select Move, you can use the cursor keys and finally Enter to reposition to a move convenient place where you see the controls.

[image]

Note: Even if you don't see the menu, for example in a Firefox in Full Screen mode (F11), if you press ALT + Space it will be created, so scrolling with the keyboard and pressing enter you can do the thing.

For example, in here I have Firefox Full Screen in the 4K monitor, and the menu appeared in the monitor Full HD to the left.
[image]

I hope this helps, at least, to avoid having to close your applications.

Answer (score 0):

This could have several problems.

Maybe:

1. It's a problem with the window manager. Does the problem exist with other window managers, too? For example openbox and others?
2. In Ubuntu there are some settings about OpenGL or other graphic libaries. Try to change it to something other.
3. Try to change the window System (maybe wayland)
4. The display manager can't cause the problem? Does sddm or other display manager cause the same behavior?
5. Maybe the screensaver cause some problems? Try deactivate Screensaver if you have it on.

But it sounds for me likely the most that it must be something with the window manager. Maybe try reconfiguring. If you use GNOME it must be something like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell
```

or a reinstall.